# Focus last modified cell when opening Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, focus

When I open an Excel file with a large number of cells, I want it to focus the last modified cell, i.e., the last cell in which I entered/changed data the last time I used Excel.

How can I automatically make Excel focus the last modified cell when opening an Excel file?

Comment: Do you want this to happen for a specific file or for all files you open in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've saved your work (and do not select other cells or worksheets before closing), Excel already does what you're asking.

Otherwise, you will need to have a macro-enabled workbook to store a variable with the address of the last modified cell. Then, in the code for your workbook (default: `ThisWorkbook` in VBE), select the range referenced by the variable in the `Workbook_Open()` function.